# Max(date) and followers

Tags: sql, date, xampp, max

I have the following problem to solve in sql. I need to get for each user, the youngest user whom he/her follows. I have the these tables:

User Information Table(user_inf):

```
 +----------+------------------+---------------+
  | name     | address          | date_of_birth |
  +----------+------------------+---------------+
  | Andreas  | Martiou 25       | 1990-12-02    |
  | Anna     | Aiakidon 20      | 1989-07-15    |
  | Aris     | Papandreou 10    | 1987-03-12    |
  | Dimitris | Dodonis 3        | 1992-09-07    |
  | Katerina | 28 Oktobriou 4   | 1993-01-09    |
  | Kostas   | Kasioumi 3       | 1992-12-12    |
  | Maria    | Kalari 8         | 1993-08-31    |
  | Panos    | Aneksartisias 13 | 1991-05-27    |
  | Petros   | Panepistimiou 9  | 1992-04-15    |
  | Yannis   | Ithakis 20       | 1993-07-03    |
  +----------+------------------+---------------+
```

User that follows other user(follows):

```
+------------+------------+
  | user1_name | user2_name |
  +------------+------------+
  | Aris       | Andreas    |
  | Kostas     | Andreas    |
  | Panos      | Andreas    |
  | Petros     | Andreas    |
  | Yannis     | Andreas    |
  | Aris       | Anna       |
  | Dimitris   | Anna       |
  | Maria      | Anna       |
  | Anna       | Aris       |
  | Maria      | Aris       |
  | Panos      | Aris       |
  | Yannis     | Aris       |
  | Andreas    | Katerina   |
  | Kostas     | Katerina   |
  | Aris       | Kostas     |
  | Maria      | Kostas     |
  | Anna       | Maria      |
  | Dimitris   | Maria      |
  | Anna       | Panos      |
  | Aris       | Panos      |
  | Kostas     | Panos      |
  | Maria      | Panos      |
  | Aris       | Yannis     |
  | Maria      | Yannis     |
  +------------+------------+
```

And my code is this one:

```
  select Fol.user2_name
  from user_inf as Usr, (select user2_name, max(date_of_birth) as MaxDate
                        from user_inf as U
                        inner join follows as F
                        on (F.user2_name = U.name )
                        inner join 
                        follows as Fol
                        on(Fol.user2_name = t1.user2_name))t1
  where t1.MaxDate = Usr.date_of_birth 
  group by Fol.user2_name;
```

The problem is that everytime i only get one name of all users or at the worst case an empty set.
Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `substring_index()`/`group_concat()` trick to get the name of the youngest user.  The youngest user has the largest value for `date_of_birth`, so:

```
select f.user1_name,
       substring_index(group_concat(f.user2_name order by u.date_of_birth desc), ',', 1) as youngest
from follows f join
     user_inf u
     on f.user2_name = u.name
group by f.user1_name;
```